# Trying to auto forward an email to a parsing API with subject intact

Tags: gmail, google-admin-sdk, forwarding, email-forwarding

So this is kind of a strange/specific question having to do with Google's forwarding.  I'm trying to automatically forward emails sent to trips@my-app.com to an email parsing service called Worldmate without having the Subject of the forwarded email being changed.  Is this a thing that can be done?  If so, any idea how?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you auto-forward the mail with a forward setting or filter then the subject and body should not be modified. When you manually forward a message from the Gmail UI, Fwd: is added to the subject and the basic headers are added to the body.

Comment: you are absolutely correct.  I realized the problem late last night wasn't the subject being changed, but where the subject was located in the XML response had changed so I had to alter how I was pulling that out.  Thank You!